# Error connecting to new sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am facing problem in registering new sql server instance SQLEXPRESS in SQL Management studio 2008. when I try to connect or test the server error message appear, 
I am also facing facing same problem in any new server irrespective of the name, except the main one which was created at the time of installation and which was named same as my user ID in windows..

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

### Error connecting to 'SQLEXPRESS'.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

Comment: can you even ping the server it is on?

Comment: Try '.\SQLEXPRESS' or 'yourcomputername\SQLEXPRESS'

Comment: TITLE: Edit Server Registration Properties

Testing the registered server failed. Verify the server name, login credentials, and database, and then click Test again.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Answer (score 1):

```
are you using windows authentication or sql server authentication 
if you are using windows authentication then you have to give the sql instance name 
which sql provide by default .
if you using sql authentication then u must use the username and password which
you provide during setup
```